# A return statement in an if clause in a method causes the rest of the method to be unreachable

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with an android app I'm making. In the below code, eclipse says that everything below the first if statement is "unreachable code". But that should not be the case, since the first if statement doesn't always execute. The unreachable code error remains regardless of what string I test startTime against, what am I doing wrong?

```
public class Service implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1506952676619302741L;
  private String expireTime = "No data";
  private String startTime = "No data";
  private String value = "No data";
  private String name = "No data";  

    public long getHideTimeMillis() throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
      Time startTime = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
      Time endTime = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
      int[] startTimeSplit;
      int[] endTimeSplit;

      if(this.startTime.equals("No data"));
      {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start time is not correctly formated.");
      }

      if(this.expireTime.equals("No data"))
      {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expiry time is not correctly formated.");
      }

      startTimeSplit = splitDate(this.startTime);
      endTimeSplit = splitDate(this.expireTime);

      startTime.set(startTimeSplit[0], startTimeSplit[1], startTimeSplit[2],    startTimeSplit[3], startTimeSplit[4], startTimeSplit[5]);
      endTime.set(endTimeSplit[0], endTimeSplit[1], endTimeSplit[2], endTimeSplit[3], endTimeSplit[4], endTimeSplit[5]);

      long difference = endTime.toMillis(false)-startTime.toMillis(false);

      return (long)(difference*0.1+0.5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `;` in the if statement

```
if(this.startTime.equals("No data"));<--!!!
```

this part is every time executed and not part of the `if`

```
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start time is not correctly formated.");
}
```

because of the `throw` the code below is unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `;` from this statement:

```
if(this.startTime.equals("No data"));
                                    ↑
```

This causes your method to always throw an `IllegalArgumentException` and thus the rest of the method is unreachable